# Inserting multiple checkbox values to one MySQL field

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox

I want to insert multiple checkbox values to a table using this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value"1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value"2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value"3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value"4" />

$category = implode(",",$_POST["category"]);
```

But in mysql it appears as "on,on".

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but you should research how to design mysql databases using normalization.  No database field should ever have multiple values separated by commas like that.  You should instead have a separate table and use joins to handle the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should be `value="1"` instead of `value"1"`. You have missed to add `=` in value attribute. So that it is not considered as value and so that it takes default value as `on`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="4" />
```

Comment: It happens some time mate!